# No TTS voices on Firefox v102.0 after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, snap, text-to-speech

My Firefox version is 102.0.1.

I upgraded my desktop from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS.

I noted now that Firefox was installed under snapd.

I noticed these events happening on my system:

1. No voices on getVoices()
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices
2. On my system,

```
$ spd-say -O
OUTPUT MODULES
espeak-ng-mbrola
espeak-ng

$ spd-say -L
NAME   LANGUAGE  VARIANT
```

spd-say -L outputs an empty table, even though spd-say "Hello world" works.

The second module espeak-ng has voices installed. Running spd-say -o espeak-ng -L produces a long table.

The problem is that the default output module has no voices. How do I set the default module?

3. spd-conf -d works

Is this a permission issue? Is TTS needed to be enabled somewhere?

Best Regards,
Configentia

Comment: It's pretty likely that the reason is snapd. You may want to remove the firefox snap and install a deb package instead. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/590937) is how it can be done.

Comment: Hi @mook765 

1. I managed to remove Firefox from snapd as per the link you gave and installed as a deb package.

2. There are still no voices in the voice array. 

What can be done?

Thank you.

Comment: I have made some observations and updated the problem description. Please see the above problem description.

Comment: I reported it as a bug, because to me it clearly is a regression, a feature that is supposed to work and has worked before. bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1987979

Comment: As I can see in the bug report I filed and in the release notes for 22.04 Ubuntu/Canonical and Mozilla are actively working to improve experience with snapped Firefox on Ubuntu which also benefits Flatpak in some areas. While I was not happy with my experience with snapped Firefox not surviving a day in previous releases due to updates, it is now informing me that it has an update scheduled. There is a blog series you can also follow to be in the loop: https://ubuntu.com/blog/improving-firefox-snap-performance-part-3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I did not encounter the problem you are describing myself, but I just created a new TTS utility which could help you as well.
It works offline, for free with AI-based high-quality voice. You can you it everywhere: Firefox browser, PDF reader, chrome, LibreOffice, etc.

Feel free to have a look, I just created a video tutorial with installation steps and DEMO: https://youtu.be/hb1ZVwUcPCU

Download link and Project page: https://github.com/MattePalte/Verbify-TTS

Feel free to leave comment/open issue to discuss new ideas, problems or constructive criticism.

Hoping it will help you.

Comment: I tried it and filed a bug on your repository. Having a requirements file with old dependencies that don't work on a newer version of Ubuntu which the OP's question was about is not so nice. My Python skills aren't great and could be improved, if I had more time I'd support you project by bringing it on track with these best practices and tools: https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-01-setup/ https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/371/pipx-installable-isolated-python-applications